# Return is not reached in debug-mode after Join to entities in DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, task-parallel-library

I don't have strong knowledge in TPL. Maybe I misunderstood some points.
I have a linq-query to entities and JOIN-operator I use to connect diffrent DBSet with diffrent entities. The result list contains INNER JOIN selection. Here is :

```cs
public async Task<List<PlantsViewModel>> GetPlants()
{
    var plants = _context.Plants
        .Join(await _context.Saptransfer.ToListAsync(), plant => plant.PlantNumber, sap => sap.Plant,
        (plant, sap) => new
        {
            plant.PlantNumber,
            plant.Plant,
            plant.PlantManager,
            plant.District,
            plant.Area
        }).GroupBy(x => new
        {
            x.PlantNumber,
            x.Plant,
            x.PlantManager,
            x.District,
            x.Area
        }).ToList();

    return plants.
        Select(p => new PlantsViewModel
        {
            PlantID = p.Key.PlantNumber,
            PlantName = p.Key.Plant,
            PlantSupervisor = p.Key.PlantManager,
            DistrictName = p.Key.District,
            RegionName = p.Key.Area
        }).OrderBy(p => p.PlantName).ToList();
}
```

First of all, it consumes much time to execute - the non-clustered indexes're abscent. But main question - why break-point near return not switched during run-time? Maybe someone will advise me how to make linq-query in a right way. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using async INSIDE a query?

Comment: The fact that you're calling `ToListAsync` inside that `Join` means that you are pulling all the data back into your app first, then doing the join. I think you need to do a bit of research and learn how to do LINQ to Entities queries properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have did a big mistake when put everywhere `ToList/Async`. LINQ query is effective when you materialize objects at the end.
I have no idea why you have put join without using it's values and then `GroupBy` for removing duplicates, but this query will be more effective that in original question:

```cs
public Task<List<PlantsViewModel>> GetPlants()
{
    var plants = 
        from plant in _context.Plants
        join sap in _context.Saptransfer on sap.Plant equals plant.PlantNumber
        group plant by new {         
            plant.PlantNumber,
            plant.Plant,
            plant.PlantManager,
            plant.District,
            plant.Area
        } into g
        orderby g.Key.Plant
        select new PlantsViewModel
        {
            PlantID = g.Key.PlantNumber,
            PlantName = g.Key.Plant,
            PlantSupervisor = g.Key.PlantManager,
            DistrictName = g.Key.District,
            RegionName = g.Key.Area
        };

    return plants.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, in this case we should not use async await in query to entities in DBSet and we should not create any tasks and like this - just run synchrooneusly query to 2 DBSet. The problem with productivity will be solved with non-clustered indexes on sap.Plant and plant.PlantNumber ?

Comment: My sample runs async query. don't be misled that I have removed `async` and `await`, they just not needed here. We cannot solve indexes problem. My query will speedup your query in several times, because it do not loads too much data into the memory. Take seriously my notes: WHY so you join to table and do not use it's result and WHY do you make `GroupBy`?

Comment: For 1 point what  do you mean as it's result? GroupBy is not necessary?

Comment: `GroupBy` without aggregations means that you are trying to filter out duplicates. And usually it means that join keys are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your query. Firstly the grouping looks to be completely unnecessary, at worst case with the join you might need to use a `Distinct` to avoid duplicates, but this can possibly also be avoided. `GroupBy` would normally be used where you want to aggregate data, such as getting a count, a minimum or maximum. or simply group related records by a detail, which your query is not doing. The next issue is that you have declared the method as `async` yet the bulk of the query is synchronous (`ToList`, not `ToListAsync`) plus you are fetching the entire grouped aggregate set of the data before projecting just the values you care about for the view model. (Doing a `ToList` before a `Select`)

Assuming the Plant and SapTransfer tables don't share a FK relationship, joining this table is effectively only filtering Plants that have a matching record in the SapTransfer table. If that is the intended behavior then you can try the following:

```
public async Task<List<PlantsViewModel>> GetPlants()
{
    var plants = _context.Plants
        .Join(_context.Saptransfer, plant => plant.PlantNumber, 
            sap => sap.Plant,
            (plant, sap) => new
            {
                plant.PlantNumber,
                plant.Plant,
                plant.PlantManager,
                plant.District,
                plant.Area
            }).OrderBy(p => p.Plant)
        .Select(p => new PlantsViewModel
        {
            PlantID = p.PlantNumber,
            PlantName = p.Plant,
            PlantSupervisor = p.PlantManager,
            DistrictName = p.District,
            RegionName = p.Area
        }).Distinct();

    return await plants.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you much, now it's clear for me

Comment: Whups, there was an error in the query, the `await` and `ToListAsync` should be on the `return`.

Comment: Do you mean that in your case og coding          return plants.ToListAsync();   without async in a method and without await before return will run synchroneusly instead of asynchroneusly?

Comment: But I still can't understand

Comment: Actually no, it was more of a brain-fog moment for me, I don't think it really matters whether you `await` & `ToListAsync` on assigning plants and just return plants, or do the `await` & `ToListAsync` on the return... Wrote that example in my head, not VS so for some reason I thought there might be a compiler error the other way. :/

Comment: But my question was why I couldn't reach in debug-mode return plants in my question code, and I still can't understand why my break-point near return doesn't work